# Jquery ui draggable mobile version

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have a problem with my slider from jquery ui. i added

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
$(".ui-slider-handle").draggable({
            axis: "x",
            containment: "parent"
        });
```

> the everything works correctly but the values doesn't shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED

```
  $('#slider1').slider().slider('pips').draggable({
            axis: "x",
            containment: "parent"
        }).slider('float',{
            suffix: " RON"
        });

    $('#slider2').slider().slider('pips').draggable({
        axis: "x",
        containment: "parent"
    }).slider('float',{
        suffix: " zile"
    });
```